# Autocompletion on Angular 2 form with Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, materialize

Today I want to talk to you about a problem i have with autocompletion. I'm working on a Angular 2 RC4 Project and i have to create some forms. Some input's form must have an autocompletion to help the users.

With the Angular magic, when you write in an input with an ngModel the inuput's data is automaticly save in an ordinary variable we've chose.

```
[(ngModel)]="myVariable"
```

So ! i'm using the autocompetion from Materialize css ! When i write in the input, the autocompletion works and shows me several solutions. However 
when i click on one of my solutions, it appears in my input but doesn't change the data from my variable.

Here is my input code !

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <input placeholder="Unité" id="srcUnit" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.fields[0].resource.unit"
           class="autocomplete"
           name="srcUnit" materialize="autocomplete"
           [materializeParams]="[{data:unitsList}]">
    <label for="srcUnit">Unité</label>
</div>
```

All my ngModel Inputs work when they don't have the autocompletion

Thank for your help !